# In Signalr Hub getting Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated false

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-identity, signalr-hub

In all api and breeze api controllers I get the identity as authenticated but I recently added Signalr and mapped signalr as you can see below my code. Its always giving the user identity not authenticated. I don't know where the problem I have also set the authentication mode to "Forms" in web.config as suggested in an answer.

```
 app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };

            //app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
            app.MapSignalR();
```

Now in OnConnected() method of Signalr

```
public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;//name is ""
            //..IsAuthticated == false also
            _connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);
            CheckSendMessagesToUser(name);

            return base.OnConnected();
        }
```

Comment: Do you have Authorize attribute on your hub class.

Comment: No. I don't have Authorize attribute on the hub class.